# Could the Sending spell be used to message to a reborn creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Could the *Sending* spell be used to send a message to a target who was killed and reborn in the Nine Hells?

The target was a PC (warlock of Dispater (Titivilus?)) who accomplished a very important task for his master and was granted the boon to be reborn as chain devil, not a lemure. Some time after that he died and was reborn at Dis of Nine Hells as a chain devil by its infernal contract.

The spellcaster who is casting *sending* doesn't know this fact and assumes that the  target is alive.  He knows the target's name and had close connections with him.

Comment: To add on to what NautArch is asking: lore-wise, souls are reborn as Lemures (pg 68 of Monster Manual), not as Chain Devils, which are immortal jailers for the Lemures that are manifested by mortal souls. Is the sending message intended for a "reborn" (or, perhaps, re-manifested would be more apt) *Lemure* or for a Chain Devil?

Comment: @Rykara for a reborned as a Chain Devil, not a Lemure. It was not a typical reborn.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the specifics mechanics around being reborn?

Comment: @NautArch No any specific mechanics, It is just a gift from the Dispater (Titivilus?) for a very nice work. After Target Character death he should go to the Nine Hells as a lemure, but Dispater (Titivilus?) takes his soul as chain devil instead. Nothing more specific is here.

Answer (score 7):

## Ask your DM

Unfortunately, we can't answer this for you. This is a homebrew mechanic that has happened at your table and is defined by your DM. Because of that, only your DM will be able to tell you what's needed, if it will work, or anything else. This includes both the reborn mechanic as well as the terms of the contract.

Ultimately, it will depend on whether or not the creature is the exact same creature or if the reborn mechanic your DM is using turns it into something else.

## If you are the DM

If you're trying to figure out how the mechanics should work, it really is completely up to you in the story that you want to tell. You can make it work however you would like it to work to progress the story

If you make the contract have the creature remain the creature but in a different form, then the *sending* should work. But if they are no longer the same creature per the terms of the contract, then when the caster tries to call they will it will just be a dead line.

## Chance of failure

Just remember that if the caster is not on the same plane that there is a 5% chance of failure no matter what.

Comment: Okay, but how should it work for default contract which makes you a lemure after your death?

Comment: @Ohar That should probably be a separate question. Are you the DM in this case?

Comment: Yup, I am the DM here

Comment: @Ohar Yeah, I'd ask that question specifically. But in the case of your actual need, I really would recommend doing what's best for the story with your players.