# What happens with a person's identity as they become a lemure?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

What happens with a person's identity after they become a lemure at Nine Hells?

Do they remember their previous life in the Material Plane? Do they remember their previous name? Do they remember their friends or foes?

Is it possible to communicate with them using a *sending* spell?

Comment: based on [our conversation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165405/could-the-sending-spell-be-used-to-message-to-a-reborn-creature/165441#165441), I'm not sure this is actually what you're trying to ask. I think what you really want to ask whether or not when a creature is transformed to a lemure if they are in fact the same creature or a different one.

Comment: @NautArch this gets into issues about the existence of souls in D&D 5e; we have a few Q&A about that.

Comment: @NautArch Nope, its a different question. I already understood that it doesn't matter if lemure is the same creature or not if they have no memory.

Comment: @Ohar Why do you think that's the case? That should probably be a separate question to confirm that assumption. I just thought you were interested in knowing if the transition to a lemure meant the creature remained the same creature with a new form or if they transformed into a brand new creature.

Comment: If this were for Pathfinder, I would know the answer for sure, and it's a definite "No" with a *single* way to get around it. Since we're talking D&D, though, I'm not sure :/

Comment: But I also think you've got two separate questions in here that need to be separated: 1) do they retain memory and 2)can you communicate with a *sending* spell.

Comment: @NautArch Is suppose that is the same case because it has no difference by practical meaning — if your mesage would send to out-of-memory creature or to noone.

Comment: @Ohar I think you're making an assumption about that. If you'd like to ask if the recipient of *sending* message that doesn't know who they are would still get it, that would be another (but separate) valid question to ask.

Comment: [a related question and answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156498/22566)

Comment: Ohar, what problem are you trying to solve by getting this question answered? Are you asking as a DM, or as a player in another DM's game?  What will knowing the answer to this do for you in playing in this campaign, or in running this campaign as DM?

Comment: This question would be answerable without the complicating bit about sending.

Comment: @Verdan We're waiting on more details and clarity, but you've provided a sort of an answer in comments which try to not to do here.